# onSaveInstanceState() called before onCreateView()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using android databinding and I'm inflating the layout of my fragment into a global `binding` variable with:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

I received some nullpointer crashes with crashlytics pointing at this line:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    binding.mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

The error is:
`Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView net.kjulio.myapp.databinding.MyFragmentBinding.mapView' on a null object reference;`

Why so? It seems to me this would only be possible if `onSaveInstanceState()` was called before `onCreateView()`. Is this possilbe?

Comment: I observed the exact same behavior on Android 6. `onSaveInstanceState()` was triggered  by the activity's `onSaveInstanceState()`. The interference of the activity and the fragment lifecycles is a mess.

Comment: what was your solution to this problem?

Comment: It is expected behavior: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

```
Note however: this method may be called at any time before onDestroy(). There are many situations where a fragment may be mostly torn down (such as when placed on the back stack with no UI showing), but its state will not be saved until its owning activity actually needs to save its state.
```

The only way I see around that is to avoid calling `binding.mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` when the fragment's view has already been destroyed.

Comment: @MarcoRomano But the quote doesn't explain why it is called before `onCreateView()` which should be called when the hosting `Activity.onCreate() `finishes.

Comment: The quote says that `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` can be called anytime before `Fragment.onDestroy()`.
This entails that `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` can be invoked before `Fragment.onCreateView(...)`.

Comment: Are you nulling out the binding in `onDestroyView()`? That would be my guess